# How to read raw audio data sent by BT

Tags: python, audio, bluetooth, wav

I'm trying to read raw data sent from a BT recording device in python.
The device is closed so I don't know the streaming format it uses.

I have code in python that listens to the BT characteristic value updated.
The raw data looks like this:

```
bytearray(b'\x08\x91\x91\x00\x91\x00\x00\t\x11\t\x91\x01\x99\x01\t\x19\x19\t\x10\x99\x02\x00\x99\x01)\x90\x91)\x99!\t\x99!\x1a\n\x91\x92\x99\x11\t\x90\x11\x91\xa1\x91\x91\x92\x99\x91\x10\x1a\x0b\x00 \x99\x01\x19\xa1\x11\x99\x19\x10\t\x01\x19\x90\x01\x19\x0c\t\x11\t\x92\x01\xa9\x11\t\x91\x1a\x00\x11\x99\x91\x10\x90\r\x92\x91\xa1\x10\x1b\x11\x19\x90\x11\t\x90!\x9a\x91\x12\xaa\x0e\x03\t\xa0\x12\t\xa1\x11\x99\x19\x10\t\x01\x19\t\x00)\x0f\x991\xba\x12\x11\xba\x11)\x90\x01\x91\x91\x92\x99\x01\x91\x00\x10\x9a)\x11\x90\x92\xa0\x11\x91\x91\x90\x92\x01\xb1\x91\x19\x01\x91\t\x19\x19\x01\x19\x91\x92\x90\x91\x00\x90\x11\x99\x92\x91\x02\t\x91\x19\x00\x10\t\x00\x11\x99\x10\t\x10\x19\t\x19\x10\x03\x00\x1a\x92\x00\x01\x90\xa1\x11\x99\x92\x19\x90\x11\n\x01\x19\x04\x90\x11\x99\x00\x10\x19\x9a1\x90\x99\x10\x10\t\x19\x10\t\x05\x10\x01\x99\x19\x10\x00\x19\x90\x11\n\x00\x19\x00\x11\x99\x91')
```

I get about 9 chunks like this every second.

I tried many variations and found that this line of codes works best in understanding the meaning of the raw data:

```
for section in struct.iter_unpack("<beeeeeeee",data):
    print (section)
```

I get this 14 sections composed of one index number (0-15) & 8 2 byte floats:

```
(14, 0.0301971435546875, -0.00022161006927490234, -0.84130859375, 10.1484375, -0.74072265625, 4.0078125, -0.0025043487548828125, -0.69189453125)
(15, 0.1297607421875, -0.04473876953125, 0.1292724609375, -0.0007157325744628906, -11.078125, 49.09375, 1.4901161193847656e-06, -0.0005536079406738281)
(0, -0.11346435546875, 0.0005841255187988281, 0.00015366077423095703, 4.64320182800293e-05, -0.9033203125, 0.0221099853515625, 0.0021419525146484375, 0.0217437744140625)
(1, -0.00409698486328125, -0.002368927001953125, 0.0401611328125, -0.00283050537109375, -0.05206298828125, -5.435943603515625e-05, -0.00019669532775878906, 12312.0)
(2, 0.00012302398681640625, -0.0006847381591796875, -1.2978515625, -0.0005645751953125, 0.18994140625, -0.8349609375, 14360.0, -0.0005002021789550781)
(3, 0.1939697265625, -0.00018525123596191406, -0.974609375, -0.053131103515625, 1.5735626220703125e-05, 0.01381683349609375, -0.0008597373962402344, -0.00016033649444580078)
(4, 0.00061798095703125, -0.00513458251953125, -0.01119232177734375, 0.00031685829162597656, 0.0008287429809570312, 0.00015652179718017578, 0.0005116462707519531, 0.0035114288330078125)
(5, -0.0033473968505859375, 0.482666015625, 0.00806427001953125, 49.09375, 0.0008587837219238281, -1.5791015625, -4.2498111724853516e-05, -0.080078125)
(6, -0.0007071495056152344, -0.06353759765625, 0.00115203857421875, 0.1331787109375, -0.0004930496215820312, 0.0025424957275390625, -0.72412109375, 41.09375)
(7, -0.0008068084716796875, 0.2020263671875, -0.0024585723876953125, 0.00794219970703125, -11.3515625, 0.0001983642578125, -0.053131103515625, 0.00794219970703125)
(8, -0.83349609375, -0.0032196044921875, -253.5, 0.00067138671875, -0.0024890899658203125, 58.71875, -9.5367431640625e-07, 48.625)
(9, -0.04718017578125, 3.505859375, -1.025390625, 1.0967254638671875e-05, -295.25, 4.0590763092041016e-05, -1.2822265625, 0.0184478759765625)
(10, -0.00513458251953125, 0.0184326171875, -0.0035419464111328125, 0.02197265625, -0.00018906593322753906, 0.0011682510375976562, -0.08203125, 0.01508331298828125)
(11, -16.375, 0.014892578125, -0.0035247802734375, -4.0650367736816406e-05, -0.003543853759765625, 0.0186920166015625, 0.541015625, -0.00937652587890625)
```

The numbers just look like static noise.
I have no knowledge in audio formats and I don't know if I am unpacking the data correctly.
I know that the device can create mono 4000hz wav files.

I'd appreciate any guidance
Thanks

Comment: How do you know they are "2 bytes floats"?

Comment: It is unusual for Bluetooth to use a BLE characteristic for sending audio as, generally speaking, it does not have the data rate to send the audio at the required rate. What is the UUID of the characteristic being used? If it is sending the audio data it is likely to need a [codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_codecs) to get the compression.

Comment: According to struct.iter_unpack documentation-  'e' is  a half-precision floating-point format but I could have used  'H' instead for unsigned short. 
In any case the numbers don't seem to mean anything.
I'll have to get back to you on the UUID.
The recording device is for hearing heartbeats ( like a stethoscope ) .
The calculations I did show that there is no way near enough data sent for a 4000hz mono sound track so it could be using a codec. If so, What about the  apparent index number at the beginning of every section ( from 0-15 )?

Comment: BLE_SERVICE_UUID = 'f1de0ef3-6e8f-4fa6-b538-5bd318bdbccb'
BLE_READ_UUID = 'c320d257-d7be-46ac-9a37-7a4edfa84bce'